# javascript popup menu and redirect url

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I used Tinybox 
http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/

to open a popup web page.
I hope when I click the links on the web page, the popup web page will close and automatically redirect to the link url I click

my javascript codes and html codes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function openJS(){}
function closeJS(){}

function closeAndGotoURL{ 
TINY.box.hide();
opener.location.href='http://www.google.com';
}


 <a href="#"  onclick="TINY.box.show({iframe:'webpage2.html',boxid:'frameless',width:750,height:450,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40,closejs:function(){closeJS()}})">Open page2</a>


//...below is on webpage2.html, it does not work

<a href="#" onclick="closeAndGotoURL()"> Click </a>
```

but this looks like not to work

Comment: When you click on a link on that popup webpage, does it open the link in the current window or a new window?

Comment: I hope to open a new url on the current window

Comment: Have you tried using `document.location` instead of `opener.location.href`?

Comment: You're also going to be running into issues with iFrames running scripts on the main page.  Does the iFrame need to call Javascript on the parent window?  Why not put the handler to direct in your "closeJS" function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `opener.location.href`, use `parent.location.href`. See below:

```
function closeAndGotoURL {
    TINY.box.hide();
    parent.location.href='http://www.google.com';
}
```

You could also use `top.location.href`:

```
function closeAndGotoURL {
    TINY.box.hide();
    top.location.href='http://www.google.com';
}
```

Another option would be to use pure HTML. Although it wouldn't close the pop up first, it would redirect the entire window to your URL. Notice the `target` attribute of the anchor tag.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_top">
```

**NOTE 1:** Why close the pop up first? If you're redirecting the whole page, just redirect - no need to close the pop up.

**NOTE 2:** This will only work properly if the page that is loaded in the iframe is on the same domain as the parent window (I'm assuming that it is since you're writing the pop up code).